# Is there an advantage to playing Waluigi?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I always found weird that it seems most people that are high ranking in Mario Kart 8 plays Waluigi.

Always tought that for some reason, most tryhards just gravitate towards that character, but seeing the MK8 tournament this weekend half the field was running Waluigi.

So it really made me wonder: Is there any factual advantage to playing Waluigi? or it's just a meme I'm missing to play Waluigi?

Comment: I know character weight is important, with lighter characters having better acceleration but lower top speed, and heavier characters having lower acceleration but better top speed. As for why Waluigi is chosen, I'm not sure!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Chase247 made a good video explaining why players pick Waluigi.

To summarize, characters in Mario Kart 8 have hidden stats that go beyond what's shown to the player. Waluigi has a decent balance of the three most important stats:  Speed, Weight, and Mini-Turbo.

[image: character stats]

Additionally, Waluigi has a skinny frame compared to most other racers, blocking less of your view of the track than characters with the same stats like DK or Roy.

Comment: I want to believe that everyone just picks Waluigi because he's a fan favourite and criminally underappreciated by Nintendo.

Comment: @MechMK1 I think there's a lot of that yes, but it doesn't exactly concern the highest rated persons

Comment: He is a balanced character, but I think there's no solid reason that players pick this specific character. I use a bunch of other random characters and still get the same result. But most of the time you see Waluigi, he's on a Wild wiggler with either a standard roller or azure rollers.